deploying my app NodeJs Autodesk Forge on server
I have created an application following the autodesk viewer hubs tutorial to test how to deploy my apps to the server.
Everything works locally, but on the server the endpoints are not working.
localhost:8080/aa/
Why doesn't it work when I upload it to the server, if the endpoints and the whole app works locally in /aa?
I have already checked the callback and everything, it works locally!
Thanks for your ideas
I work with Node Js, Express

What kind of issue you had after deploying to server? failed to login? any details?

Finally my colleague fixed this problem by modifying the proxy.
My application now works without subroutes locally and with subroutes on the server. I have modified the routes in my frontend and also some in the endpoints: res.redirect('../../')
I just modified the autodesk callback for the application.

cool, good it works.
